# Backwards engineering MySQL table (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I found a Wordpress plugin called [Extra Comment Fields](http://blog.ideashower.com/post/15147134893/wordpress-plugin-extra-comment-fields#download) that should work, but I'm having trouble with the database! Extra fields are not stored anywhere!

Table plugin uses (and should create) is called wp_comments_extra, but this table is nowhere to be found. Is there any way to manually crate correct table by backwards- engineering plugin's .php file?

Answer (score 0):

You should never have to do that. In fact it would be a really bad idea to. Usually modifying plugins can cause a lot of problems if you don't know what you are doing. What are you trying to do? The table should be created automatically when you activate the plugin.

What makes you think that is the table that would be created, anyways? It could use Wordpress built in meta tables, rather than it's own. Not every plugin creates a table named after itself.

And besides, that plugin hasn't been worked on since 2008. It could be incredibly out of date. If I were you I would look for a different plugin.